# TypeScript: how do I initialize members of a class using setters without using a definite assignment assertion?

Tags: typescript

The following TypeScript code fails to compile with `strictNullChecks` and `strictPropertyInitialization` enabled:

```js
class SampleClass {
    private _foo: string;

    constructor(foo: string) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public get foo() {
        return this._foo;
    }

    public set foo(foo: string) {
        this._foo = foo;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that "Property '_foo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

I can work around this by adding a definite assignment assertion to `_foo`, but I don't see why one is necessary. The constructor calls the setter for `foo`, which in turn sets `_foo`. Is this a bug, or is there something I'm not understanding?

I am using the latest version of TypeScript at the time of writing (3.2.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24937) for which definite assignment assertions are indeed the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug

Nope, you've stated yourself that you are running strict mode typescript.

> is there something I'm not understanding

This code:

```
private _foo: string;
```

having no initializer means that when your class instantiates, you will have type of _foo `undefined`, BUT you've stated the type `string`, and NOT `string | undefined`. Hence, you could do one of this:

```
private _foo?: string;
// or
private _foo: string | undefined;
```

And you will be able to avoid initialization of that property.

That modification will lead to other related ones in your class.

Comment: But `_foo` is definitely assigned in the constructor. The constructor calls the setter for `foo`, which assigns a value to `_foo`.

Comment: @MichaelKourlas While you're right, Typescript simply doesn't look at things like this. It's none of its business. Maybe in future they will add such a feature (doubt), but currently this kind of inferrer doesn't exist. Just read the docs, and you will get the picture of exactly what TS is capable of.

Comment: It looks like you're correct that TypeScript [can't do this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24937), though this seems to me like a significant limitation. AFAIK, TypeScript does similar control flow analysis in other contexts; it's a shame that they can't or won't do it here.

Comment: @MichaelKourlas Oh believe me there are far, far more significant issues and bugs in TS. But still there are not many good alternatives to it, if any.